# Django Set Language not working

Tags: django

I am working on a website right now. I have started working on internationalizing it.

The code for the language selection menu is

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    <select name="language">
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

But it does not seem to work. It just redirects to the same page

I have added

1. `(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))` to `urls.py`;
2. `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to
   `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py
3. `'django.core.context_processors.i18n',` to
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS  in settings.py

Should I import anything?

**UPDATE**

Wenever I add

```
LANGUAGES = (
  ('es', _('Spanish')),
  ('en-US', _('AmericanEnglish')),
)
```

to the settings.py I get

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Otherwise at least the website works

Comment: try to remove the \_( ) around language names or at least do something like _ = lambda n:n (_ as a noop function)

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Could you post your solution if you finally fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to the same page is the default of django.views.i18n.set_language view (unless you send a different url in next param).

I suggest you to check if the language cookie is set or not (as anonymous user).

If the cookie is not set check that language code you're sending is correct.

Note that a language code is valid (in Django's mind) only if "its" locale code maps to a folder in django/conf/locale (not only a folder but a correct locale folder like locale_code/LC_MESSAGES/django.po)

having a look in django.utils.translations.trans_real.py (language check, lang to locale...) and in django/views/i18n.py helps a lot :)

Comment: I tried web inspector: `document.cookie`. Output is :

`"fc=fcVal=7798277497960028864; sessionid=cf940433f6b2349d0284a9110ed87018; csrftoken=56cb4e4b9827de8837097e877a847fb9; __utma=224519516.441384761.1323800951.1323800951.1323800951.1; __utmb=224519516.9.10.1323800951; __utmc=224519516; __utmz=224519516.1323800951.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); arp_scroll_position=0"`

Do u think the cookie is set?

Comment: clear all cookies first, if you have a session than the language it's stored in the session (and you don't see a LANG coookie)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are sending [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext).

`return render_to_response('foo.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit `<input name="next" value="/" type="hidden"/>` to the form to redirect to site root. Otherwise it didn't work for me.